LiftDrag plugin for Gazebo garden parameters
I'm trying to simulate (accurately) a Cessna 172 using Gazebo garden, which implies using the LiftDrag plugin to simulate the aerodynamic forces. Looking at other models such as zephyr with ardupilot and wsc aircraft (https://github.com/ArduPilot/SITL_Models/tree/master/Gazebo/models/wsc_aircraft) i've noticed that forces applied by the control surfaces are modeled by means of aerodynamic coefficients, however i'm not sure how i could compute the correct coefficients starting from the desired force/torque values. Is that the only way to model the control surfaces or is there a way to directly input the desired forces as a function of the servos position and alpha? Any help, incuding a link to some documentation or some paper would be very appreciated
